# "no bootable device" after unsuccessful dual boot install attempt

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

I wanted to dual boot Xubuntu with Windows. I didn't notice that the laptop wasn't plugged in until it was too late. I still need to keep Windows, but I don't know how to boot it.

Comment: Try reinserting the LiveCD, deleting the Linux partitions but not the unmodified Windows one, then restarting the installer

Comment: You mention "*I didn't notice that the laptop wasn't plugged in*" which implies your system turned off during an install??   If so, your disk partition(s) could be corrupted and you need to boot *live* media and fix that. The easiest fix for your Xubuntu is to just re-install it, to fix your prior windows, you can use your windows recovery media.. If the system was still shrinking partitions however, you may have lost data & thus need to re-install & recover data from your backups.  You details are unclear, and provide no version details at all (Xubuntu release is? etc)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

Comment: I doubt the Windows partition is lost. I doubt any partition is lost. The Ubuntu installer writes the partition table at the beginning, and the GRUB installer at some other time. It is not likely that the power loss occurred at that specific time. It most likely happened when Ubuntu was copying files, in which case only the Linux partitions would be corrupt. In that case, deleting and recreating the Linux partitions should work.